# For loop across binomial probabilities in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, probability

Hi I have a list of x values (x for the nCx formula for binomial probability) and a list of probabilities that I have to iterate over.

`x=c(8,16,24,32)`

`p=c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.15)`

Basically I want to compute the combinations of these two vectors using the nCx formula and pbinom in R... I should essentially end up with a 4x4 matrix with probabilities. The 'q' parameter in my question is always 1.

Can someone let me know the simplest way to do this?

Comment: `nCx` means *`n` choose `x`*?

Comment: `pbinom` has three mandatory arguments: `pbinom(q, size, prob, ...)`, the `q`uantiles, number of trials, and probability, respectively. Which is missing?

Comment: yes! the binomial probability P(X=x)=nCx(p)^x(1-p)^(n-x)

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that q is always 1 in my question

Comment: and another alt; `ex = expand.grid(x=c(8,16,24,32), p=c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.15)); ex$pv = with(ex, pbinom(1, x, p))` (is it maybe dbinom that's needed?)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```r
outer(x, p, FUN = function(S, P) pbinom(1, S, P))
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
# [1,] 0.9973099 0.9427553 0.8131047 0.65718303
# [2,] 0.9890671 0.8107597 0.5147278 0.28390121
# [3,] 0.9761456 0.6608173 0.2924770 0.10592423
# [4,] 0.9593174 0.5199624 0.1564234 0.03664672
```

Verification: the second `x` and the third `p` should show up on row 2 column 3,

```r
pbinom(1, x[2], p[3])
# [1] 0.5147278
```